# Linux Jenkins test if file exists in windows share

Tags: linux, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a master Linux Jenkins server. I need to test if a file exists on a remote windows share using the pipeline.

is there an easy way to do this? I have learnt that 'fileExists' only works for the local workspace so that's no good.

Is this possible? Or would I need to do some magic using an sh command instead?

Thanks!

Craig

Comment: use NFS to connect remote FS as a local folder. check this folder.

Comment: If the ssh server is running on your windows machine, just exchange keys and connect via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [LFTP](https://lftp.yar.ru/) installed on the Jenkins server, you could try the following

```
$ lftp -c "open sftp://hostname_remote_windows_system ; find file_to_be_found.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `fileExists()`need to be executed on a node. So: How about having a windows node connected to you Linux master doing the `fileExists()`, like:

```
def fileDoesExist
node('windows') {
    fileDoesExist = fileExists(pathToFile)
}
```

Please note that accessing a windows file share needs a `net use` one time. So in order to make this also work on new machines which never accessed the share before you should do:

```
def fileDoesExist
node('windows') {
    bat 'net use \\\\share\\path\\to\\some\\directory'
    fileDoesExist = fileExists('//share/path/to/file')
}

if (fileDoesExist) {
    // do someting here
}
```